# Php remove html tags when reading a page

Tags: php, html

I have a script to read Shoutcast live broadcast informations.

I am getting name of track and searching it on spotify api to get cover art.

My code:

```
$sc_url_ip = "streamip";
$sc_url_port = "streamport"; 

function getNowPlaying($sc_url_ip,$sc_url_port)
{
    $open = fsockopen($sc_url_ip,$sc_url_port,$errno,$errstr,'.5'); 
    if ($open) { 
        fputs($open,"GET /7.html HTTP/1.1\nUser-Agent:Mozilla\n\n"); 
        stream_set_timeout($open,'1');
        $read = fread($open,200);
        $text = explode(",",$read);
        if($text[6] == '' || $text[6] == '</body></html>'){ 
           $msg = ' live stream offline'; } 
        else { 
           $msg = $text[6]; 
        }
        $text = $msg; 
    } 
    else {  
        return false; 
    } 

    fclose($open);
    return $text;   
}

$current_song = getNowPlaying($sc_url_ip,$sc_url_port);
echo $current_song;
```

But when searching with spotify api, my track name look like this in source code:

```
Pink Floyd - Welcome to the Machine</body></html>
```

Because of html tags, spotify api search results zero. See search url:

https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?query=Pink+Floyd+-+Welcome+to+the+Machine%3C%2Fbody%3E%3C%2Fhtml%3E%3B&type=track

I tried strip_tags but I couldnt.
How can I remove these `</body></html>` tags from $current_song ?

Comment: You can try with PHP's [strip_tags()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php).

Comment: Yes, I tried but I dont know strip_tags to which variable

Comment: To the variable that contains the track name. Add it to the return in your function: `return strip_tags($text);`

Comment: Did you try the suggestion in my previous comment?

Comment: Yes I tried but it didn't work, thank you anyway for your help

Comment: Then you did it wrong, since that's basically exactly what the accepted answer does. My suggestion was simply to do it one step earlier in your code. :-)

Comment: Yes :) Your answer was correct but as I said I couldn't figure out that to which variable I should apply strip_tags .
You are the our heart's correct answer :)
Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `$current_song` contains the html tag right? Then to remove it, try this:

```
$current_song = strip_tags(getNowPlaying($sc_url_ip,$sc_url_port));
```

Comment: Welcome! Glad could help. :)